# Logic to find out the Maximum values of a version in java

Tags: java, string, max

I have a task to find out the maximum version available for a component among the comma separated given input.

Input would be like :

> 1.4.7.2, 1.6.1.2.1.2, 5.6, 23.7.1.1, 23.0.1, 38.3

I have to find out the maximum version among these which is : 38.3

My algorithm to solve the above is:

> 1. Remove all the spaces or any character other then numerics,. and comma from the input string
> 2. Split the input string into string array of different versions
> 3. Take the first version as the maxVersion and remove the . and take the value as the maxVaue and the length of that value as maxLength
> 4. Iterate from index 1 to end    and format each string by removing . and then compare the length with the maxlength if it is greater
>      reassign the value of maxLength
> 5. right append 0s to the maxValue and the currentValue to make both of same length i.e. maxLength
> 6. If the new Value is greater than max value , reassign the maxValue variable and also the maxVersion variable

Please provide your input how it can be efficiently done

PS: It is given that there will be only one max version
however we can expand the program to consider multiple versions having max version values

EDIT: There is another option to add all the elements in arraylist and sort the collection

Comment: It will depend on if the comparison between versions with different amounts of "sections" (dots) is interpreted Left-to-Right (super first) or Right-to-Left (sub first). For example: `1.4.7.2` VS `5.6` might be meaning `1.4.7.2` VS `5.6.*.*` or `*.*.5.6`, and different meanings give different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursively find highest version for the current "versioning section" (between dots):

> 1.4.7.2, 1.6.1.2.1.2, 5.6, 23.7.1.1, 23.0.1, 34.8

Between these, the first section highest is `34`. If there are no other instances where the first section is also `34`, you've found your highest version.

If there are; and let's assume a `34.7` since your example didn't specify such; then the process should recursively move to the second section, where `8` would be the highest.

Answer (score -1):

I'd do it like this;

```
1. Get rid of all non-numerical characters
2. Change the strings to integers and check the highest number
```

Now we run into the problem that 1.4 is a higher version than 1.3.9 but it would return 1.3.9 as the higher version. So we do this;

```
2 (rewritten). Add as many 0's to the end of the string as it's less than another, that was
a poorly written written so say string A is 3 in length, and string B is 6 in length. 3 0's
would be added unto the end of string A.

3. Change the strings to integers and check the highest number.
```

Now 1.4 will turn into 140 and 1.3.9 will turn into 139. 140 > 139.

EDIT: If you're gonna downvote, tell my why you downvoted. I'd like to improve too ya'know.